# What is a possible use case for duplicate +id layout-wide?

Tags: android, layout, android-source

We don't have a compilation problem, we just want to expand our knowledge. Reading through [Google Code Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29), we have read that +id doesn't have to be unique layout-wide.

Below a compiling example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.bq.testviewids.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hola Mundo" />

</LinearLayout>

private void initViews() {
    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    txtText.setId(View.generateViewId());
    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}

private void changeTextView() {
    txtText.setText("");
}
```

If in *initViews()* we don't have the last two lines:

```
txtText.setId(View.generateViewId());
txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

When we do a change to txtText (in *changeTextView()*), the first TextView gets modified.

If we do have the last two lines the second TextView gets modified.

We didn't know that this was possible, and we thought that if you had two items layout-wide with the same +id, it wouldn't compile. ***Now, we understand that the identifier doesn't have to be unique in this view's hierarchy***, but, we don't understand the usefulness of this behavior.

Does someone know a use case in which a non-unique identifier is useful?

This doubt comes to us when we see in ***Android for MSM*** ([**CAF**](https://www.codeaurora.org/projects/all-active-projects/android-msm)) in Settings project [this code](https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/packages/apps/Settings/tree/res/layout/wifi_ap_dialog.xml?h=LA.BR.1.3.4_rb1.31) with a duplicate id (*@+id/fields*):

```
       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/wifi_section"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/wifi_item">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/wifi_item">
            ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/wifi_section" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've edited the question, I understand the functioning of findViewById and I know that it will return the first that finds. I only want to know a use case of a duplicate identifier (+id).

Answer (score 1):

The use case that comes to mind are the duplicate id's that you would have if you have a layout that is included two or more times in another layout. It would save you the headache of trying to get unique id's in each duplicated layout.

It would also allow you to work within each included layout using the same code without having to track different id's depending upon which sub-layout you are working on.

Comment: I understand the duplicate of ids in the case of the integration of view inside other view (Listview or RecyclerView for example), but this integration is programatically, not directly in desing layout. In the same layout-wide, Do you know any use case? Thanks!!

Comment: `ListView` and `RecyclerView` are two good examples but, if I have a simple app, why couldn't I just manually include a layout within another layout several times with include statements? It doesn't have to be programmatic. That said, I believe that your example of Views with the same id with the same direct `ViewGroup` parent being allowed is an artifact of needing things like `ListView` to work. If is permitted insofar a it is not forbidden but may not be useful or good practice.

Comment: Yes, we know that this is not a good practice but our question is that why Google in 25 versions doesn't change this?

Comment: I add a real example in the question.

Comment: I see the `fields` id repeats in two `LinearLayout`s. The first has `visibility="gone"` while the second one is visible. Other ids do not repeat within these two layouts. You would have to peek at the java code for this layout to see what is going on. Since the first layout is "gone", the code may just search for the id `fields` to set it to visible (maybe toggle it on/off?) and it doesn't matter what the second layout's id is. The search will always find the first id. IMHO, this duplication of ids may just be an artifact of past changes and, since it doesn't cause a problem, just rides.

Comment: In the code, it change the visibility of the first one, but with the second, it doesn't do nothing so it doesn't work.

Comment: So, the first one is used and the second one isn't? The second one is probably just a vestige and useless as it is. (Just my guess.)

Comment: The second one is not accesible by code because the first one is returned always. findViewById only returns one view, furthermore, stops looking for more when one is found.
I understand the doubt here, why would Google do this? Are we missing something or is it just a mistake?

Comment: Here is what Android Studio v2.2.3 says about the layout in question if you put it into a project:
_"Duplicate id @+id/fields, already defined earlier in this layout (@+id/fields originally defined here)
Within a layout, id's should be unique since otherwise findViewById() can return an unexpected view."_

So, given this error messages, I would say "mistake", although not a large one since it doesn't seem to cause any problems. It could be a future bug in waiting, though.

Comment: Yes, if you do it in your own project, as Victor said, it also launches that warning, not a compilation error, but a Lint warning. Hence, why doesn't Android avoid this potential mistake in compilation, maybe there IS a useful use case for this?